# corona apk installation runtime error

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-engine

I am new to Conrona, and facing a stupid situation and I hope someone can help.

This is `menu` page
http://postimg.org/image/rbvgtj5h1/

This is `GenerateImage` class
http://postimg.org/image/uggduv6gx/

The app works fine in corona simulator!!!

However, when I generated the apk and try to install and open the application, it prompts error

> "Runtime Error" "C:\Users\Andy\Documents\Corona
>   Projects\Hero\Class_GenerateLimage.lua:10:attempt to index local
>   'image' (a nil value)

I have spent hours trying to solve it but failed, hoping someone can help me .

Comment: Pls check whether the file name and path is correct. More over check whether names are in the small or CAPS letter.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your path does not contain capital letters. So change Images to images.

I learned this was a problem on Android about a year ago.